# Inner Loop in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I have read the docs on with_nested and loops etc but not sure that they apply to my scenario.

My structure is:
org
-- org has networks
---- networks have devices
------ devices have licenses

The goal is to delete my orgs.  This can only occur when all the devices have been unlicensed, deleted, and networks delete.

Therefore what I need to do is grab a list of orgs.
-- Then loop thru that list and using the org_id get all the networks
---- For each network I then get the list of devices.
------ Then loop thru the list of devices and delete license keys 
------ Delete device.
---- Delete network
-- Delete org
loop

With there only being the one `item.x` then not sure how to get the `item` of the inner loops.

Could add code but would look like crap as I simply can't visualize this in my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more options. For example, given the data

```yaml
  orgs:
    o1:
      n1:
        d1:
          license: k1
        d2:
          license: k2
      n2:
        d3:
          license: k3
    o2:
      n3:
        d4:
          license: k4
        d5:
          license: k5
```

---

1. Use [*to_paths*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/to_paths_lookup.html#ansible-utils-to-paths-lookup-flatten-a-complex-object-into-a-dictionary-of-paths-and-values) lookup

```yaml
  orgs_paths: "{{ lookup('ansible.utils.to_paths', orgs) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  orgs_paths:
    o1.n1.d1.license: k1
    o1.n1.d2.license: k2
    o1.n2.d3.license: k3
    o2.n3.d4.license: k4
    o2.n3.d5.license: k5
```

Then, declare the lists

```yaml
  _key: "{{ orgs_paths.keys()|list }}"
  _dev: "{{ _key|map('splitext')|map('first')|unique }}"
  _net: "{{ _dev|map('splitext')|map('first')|unique }}"
  _org: "{{ _net|map('splitext')|map('first')|unique }}"
  _arr: "{{ item.split('.') }}"
```

and delete the tree

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Delete license: {{ orgs_paths[item] }} for {{ _arr[0:3] }}"
      loop: "{{ _key }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Delete device: {{ _arr.2  }} for {{ _arr[0:2] }}"
      loop: "{{ _dev }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Delete network: {{ _arr.1  }} for {{ _arr[0:1] }}"
      loop: "{{ _net }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Delete org: {{ item  }}"
      loop: "{{ _org }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Delete orgs"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'Delete license: k1 for [''o1'', ''n1'', ''d1'']'
  msg: 'Delete license: k2 for [''o1'', ''n1'', ''d2'']'
  msg: 'Delete license: k3 for [''o1'', ''n2'', ''d3'']'
  msg: 'Delete license: k4 for [''o2'', ''n3'', ''d4'']'
  msg: 'Delete license: k5 for [''o2'', ''n3'', ''d5'']'
  msg: 'Delete device: d1 for [''o1'', ''n1'']'
  msg: 'Delete device: d2 for [''o1'', ''n1'']'
  msg: 'Delete device: d3 for [''o1'', ''n2'']'
  msg: 'Delete device: d4 for [''o2'', ''n3'']'
  msg: 'Delete device: d5 for [''o2'', ''n3'']'
  msg: 'Delete network: n1 for [''o1'']'
  msg: 'Delete network: n2 for [''o1'']'
  msg: 'Delete network: n3 for [''o2'']'
  msg: 'Delete org: o1'
  msg: 'Delete org: o2'
  msg: Delete orgs
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    orgs:
      o1:
        n1:
          d1: {license: k1}
          d2: {license: k2}
        n2:
          d3: {license: k3}
      o2:
        n3:
          d4: {license: k4}
          d5: {license: k5}

    orgs_paths: "{{ lookup('ansible.utils.to_paths', orgs) }}"
    _key: "{{ orgs_paths.keys()|list }}"
    _dev: "{{ _key|map('splitext')|map('first')|unique }}"
    _net: "{{ _dev|map('splitext')|map('first')|unique }}"
    _org: "{{ _net|map('splitext')|map('first')|unique }}"
    _arr: "{{ item.split('.') }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Delete license: {{ orgs_paths[item] }} for {{ _arr[0:3] }}"
      loop: "{{ _key }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Delete device: {{ _arr.2  }} for {{ _arr[0:2] }}"
      loop: "{{ _dev }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Delete network: {{ _arr.1  }} for {{ _arr[0:1] }}"
      loop: "{{ _net }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Delete org: {{ item  }}"
      loop: "{{ _org }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Delete orgs"
```

---

2. The next option is the inclusion of tasks in loops. For example, create files

```yaml
shell> cat del_dev.yml
- block:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          Delete license {{ item.value }} for
          [{{ item_org.key }}, {{ item_net.key }}, {{ item_dev.key }}]
      loop: "{{ item_dev.value|dict2items }}"
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          Delete device {{ item_dev.key }} for
          [{{ item_org.key }}, {{ item_net.key }}]
```

```yaml
shell> cat del_net.yml
- block:
    - include_tasks: del_dev.yml
      loop: "{{ item_net.value|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_dev
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          Delete network {{ item_net.key }} for
          [{{ item_org.key }}]
```

```yaml
shell> cat del_org.yml
- block:
    - include_tasks: del_net.yml
      loop: "{{ item_org.value|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_net
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          Delete org {{ item_org.key }}
```

Recursively include the tasks in a playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    orgs:
      o1:
        n1:
          d1: {license: k1}
          d2: {license: k2}
        n2:
          d3: {license: k3}
      o2:
        n3:
          d4: {license: k4}
          d5: {license: k5}

  tasks:

    - block:
        - include_tasks: del_org.yml
          loop: "{{ orgs|dict2items }}"
          loop_control:
            loop_var: item_org
        - debug:
            msg: Delete orgs
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Delete license k1 for [o1, n1, d1]
  msg: Delete device d1 for [o1, n1]
  msg: Delete license k2 for [o1, n1, d2]
  msg: Delete device d2 for [o1, n1]
  msg: Delete network n1 for [o1]
  msg: Delete license k3 for [o1, n2, d3]
  msg: Delete device d3 for [o1, n2]
  msg: Delete network n2 for [o1]
  msg: Delete org o1
  msg: Delete license k4 for [o2, n3, d4]
  msg: Delete device d4 for [o2, n3]
  msg: Delete license k5 for [o2, n3, d5]
  msg: Delete device d5 for [o2, n3]
  msg: Delete network n3 for [o2]
  msg: Delete org o2
  msg: Delete orgs
```

---

3. Getting the structure on the fly makes the code simpler. For example, let's imagine the structure is the same as before. As the first step in each loop, we find the list of org, their networks, and devices. This is the meaning of the argument in the *loop* statement. In real life, you would probably get the lists in a separate task before the loop. Create files

```yaml
shell> cat del_dev.yml
- block:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          Delete license {{ _item }} for
          [{{ item_org }}, {{ item_net }}, {{ item_dev }}]
      vars:
        _item: "{{ orgs[item_org][item_net][item_dev]['license'] }}"
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          Delete device {{ item_dev }} for
          [{{ item_org }}, {{ item_net }}]
```

```yaml
shell> cat del_net.yml
- block:
    - include_tasks: del_dev.yml
      loop: "{{ orgs[item_org][item_net].keys()|list }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_dev
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          Delete network {{ item_net }} for
          [{{ item_org }}]
```

```yaml
shell> cat del_org.yml
- block:
    - include_tasks: del_net.yml
      loop: "{{ orgs[item_org].keys()|list }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_net
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          Delete org {{ item_org }}
```

The playbook below gives the same results

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    orgs:
      o1:
        n1:
          d1: {license: k1}
          d2: {license: k2}
        n2:
          d3: {license: k3}
      o2:
        n3:
          d4: {license: k4}
          d5: {license: k5}

  tasks:

    - block:
        - include_tasks: del_org.yml
          loop: "{{ orgs.keys()|list }}"
          loop_control:
            loop_var: item_org
        - debug:
            msg: Delete orgs
```

---

Q: ***"How to propagate the org_id due to only a single item?"***

A: Simply put this single item into the list. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    orgs:
      o1:
        n1:
          d1: {license: k1}
          d2: {license: k2}
        n2:
          d3: {license: k3}
      o2:
        n3:
          d4: {license: k4}
          d5: {license: k5}

  tasks:

    - block:
        - include_tasks: del_org.yml
          loop:
            - o2
          loop_control:
            loop_var: item_org
        - debug:
            msg: Delete orgs
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Delete license k4 for [o2, n3, d4]
  msg: Delete device d4 for [o2, n3]
  msg: Delete license k5 for [o2, n3, d5]
  msg: Delete device d5 for [o2, n3]
  msg: Delete network n3 for [o2]
  msg: Delete org o2
  msg: Delete orgs
```

Comment: Thanks .  Sorry for the ugly post.  SO comment's :(  
My problem is that this is all dynamic data, I start only having the orgs.
Then grab network (multiple) devices (singular) and licenses  
I have this working for a single org, but i cannot work out how to propagate the org_id due to only a single **item**  


My flow is:
  
```
 - name: Info about  org to be deleted  
    - name: Get a list of networks  
     - name: Get list of devices  
     - name: Remove devices from the networks  
     - name: Move Licenses  
 - name: Delete Net  
- name: Delete Org  
```

Comment: You're welcome. I added an example. If you have a problem [edit] the question and make the case [mre].

Comment: OMG - Epiphany...    loop_var.   I did not see that in the fine print, thats what allows the multiple loops.  I thought **item** was fixed.  Vladimir you rock.